# Certain tracks have crazy volume on certain speakers?

Tags: audio

I'm a new video editor and I was working on this little promo for work and when I listen to the promo with my editing headphones, or the computer speakers, or master control, everything sounds fine.

When I listen to it on a TV or my phone, though, a few sort of 'interview' shots sound way quieter and tinnier than everything else, and one in particular sounds really loud.

What causes this sound difference on TV's and phones while everything sounds perfect and level on my editing gear?

Comment: Try using woodier words. ;-} https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gwXJsWHupg

Comment: is the phone speaker mono? Could be that the stereo tracks are out of phase and cancelling each other out when they're summed to mono.

Answer (score 0):

Different speakers have different frequency response. Nicer speakers will have wider and more accurate frequency response, while lower end speakers like in phones and TVs usually don't have as much response at the low and high end of the spectrum, especially the low end. This can cause your mix to sound vastly different in different listening environments. The most important skill in audio mixing is understanding how to make your mix sound good in all listening environments.